# Unix inbox line wrapping behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, smtp, imap

I've developed an application that parses data from unix inboxes, and retrieves the messages using IMAP.  The main issue I'm running into right now is that the flat file inbox in /var/mail that stores the emails is wrapping the line and inserts an equals after 75 characters.  The strangest thing is that this occurs only within the body of the message.

```
12345678901234567890123456789098    2010-03-04  1:56:43 192.156.1.1 Microsoft F=
irefox
```

Could this be a problem with the separate SMTP server reformatting the emails, or is it a problem with the inbox or the imap server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal, read up on [Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding.

You are probably going to have to look at the `content-transfer-encoding` header for the message or the mime part.  Check if it is `quoted-printable` and then decode it.  There is almost certainly a library or function available for your programming language to do this for you.

Comment: This was the solution I needed.  I ended up using the quopri module in python to decode the emails, and it worked like a charm.  If only I had enough rep to upvote...